# How can i push value to an array in a mysql query in nodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, express

I'm trying to push a value to an array of errors, depends on the query's result.

I've tried in several ways, directly from the arrow function and defining a variable, with the number of returned records, but as i can see, the query arrow function doesn't manipulate the variable.

How can i use the number of returned records in a conditional statement?

```js
const userExistence = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS countEmail FROM users WHERE Email = ?";
mysql.db.query(userExistence, [email], (err, result) => {
  if (result[0].countEmail !== 0) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Account with this email address already exists' });
  }
        console.log(result[0].countEmail);
  console.log(err);
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: You need to know that mysql.db.query.... is async function, please paste your code here within the question so I can help you.

Comment: I thought, it's something like that, I pasted the snippet of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must evaluate errors array length within the callback function of the query since the query function is an asynchronous function.

check the code below:

```
const userExistence = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS countEmail FROM users WHERE Email = ?";
mysql.db.query(userExistence, [email], (err, result) => {
  if (result[0].countEmail !== 0) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Account with this email address already exists' });
  }

  // Add your condition here.
  if(errors.length > 0) {
  }
  else {
  }

  console.log(result[0].countEmail);
  console.log(err);
  res.end();

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but is there any way, to implement a boolean variable, or anything, to validate later, if more validation required? Or it's only possible in the query function?

Comment: It's depend on what kind of validation you want to do. @GaramvolgyiSoma

Comment: In this case only if the current email address is already registered, but what if I'd like to check Name existence too? Should I embed it in the other query, like "mysql.db.query(userExistence ... ) => { mysql.db.query( nameExistence ... ) => { if ( ..."?